# Reverse os.urandom in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have files encrypted by the code below using a 1 byte key and XOR encryption.

```
blocksize=256

while (args.secretkey.tell() < blocksize):
generates once?
    sys.stdout.write('.')
    args.secretkey.write(os.urandom(1))

counter=0
args.secretkey.seek(0)
keydata = args.secretkey.read(blocksize)

while 1:
    byte = args.infile.read(1)
    if not byte:
        break
    args.outfile.write(chr(ord(keydata[counter % len(keydata)]) ^ ord(byte)))
    counter+=1
```

How do I find the correct key to decrypt the files? Must I go through 256 combinations to get the correct key?

Comment: Uh... you were supposed to ask for more than 1 byte. Why would you even bother with a 1-byte key? And what encryption algorithm did you use?

Comment: Please show us the encryption code so we can at least guess what you are trying to do

Comment: That doesn't mean "dump your entire program on us". Use a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org) instead.

Comment: Code generates a key of 256 bytes, not just 1 byte.  If you lost the secretKey, you need to explore pow(256, 256) possibilities... quite a few

Answer (score 1):

Here you have the decoding program (the encoding is a xor against the random generated data, so the decoding is to do the same xor):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import sys
import argparse

blocksize=256

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Custom encryption algorithm because a friend said that's the way to do it. Anyway, it's called 'Only This Program' since I'm pretty sure that only this program can securely decrypt the files as long as you don't give out your secret.dat file created when you encrypt something.")
parser.add_argument('--infile', metavar='i', nargs='?', type=argparse.FileType('r'), help='input file, defaults to standard in', default=sys.stdin)
parser.add_argument('--outfile', metavar='o', nargs='?', type=argparse.FileType('wb'), help='output file, defaults to standard out', default=sys.stdout)
parser.add_argument('--secretkey', metavar='s', nargs='?', type=argparse.FileType('r'), help='input file, defaults to secretkey.dat', default='secretkey.dat')

args = parser.parse_args()

counter=0
args.secretkey.seek(0)
keydata = args.secretkey.read(blocksize)

while 1:
    byte = args.infile.read(1)
    if not byte:
        break
    args.outfile.write(chr(ord(keydata[counter % len(keydata)]) ^ ord(byte)))
    counter+=1

sys.stderr.write('\nSecret keyfile: %s\nInput file: %s\nOutput file: %s\nTotal bytes: %d \n' % (args.secretkey.name, args.infile.name, args.outfile.name, counter))
```

Comment: Sorry I am noob in this. But how do you determine the secret key? Since previously it was randomly generated.

Comment: @aandroidtest, the secret key is generated at encryption, so you need it for decryption.  If you lose it, you cannot decrypt the file (think of it as a 256-byte random generated password; the password here is strong but the encrypting algorithm is not so strong).  You will need that password.

Comment: @juanleon, I wouldn't go that far; XOR is such weak encryption that all you need to reverse-engineer the key is a bit of data of known type. See my answer...

Comment: @alexis, yes... if you have data enough (what if you have just 200 bytes, or 400?)

Comment: If you have *that* little, forget it. Each key byte must be used a few times at least, before we can conclude anything from the resulting frequencies. Even with just a few K, you can make weak guesses and then factor in more regularities of English text, e.g., " to " is more common than "bxQj". With a few hundred Kb, it becomes trivial.

Answer (score 1):

To reverse the encryption, you need the 256 byte random key. But if you've lost it, xor encryption is so weak that if you know *something* about some of your encrypted files, **you can reverse-engineer it** with a bit of patience.

For exposition, let's assume that you have several files that you know to contain English text; the same principles apply to many other types of content, though. Ideally, you need a few hundred blocks of predictable text.

1. First, note that the same "secret" byte is used to encode every 256'th byte; so you can collect a good bunch of bytes, from different text files, that were xor'ed with the same key byte (e.g., byte 0 of your key).
2. You can now count the frequencies of the encoded bytes and match them against a frequency table for English text.
3. Let's say the most frequent byte is `0xAB`; well, in English text the most frequent byte is space (`0x20`); it's almost twice as frequent as the next most common byte (`e`), so it's hard to go wrong if you're looking at text files. So, just solve the little equation `0x20 ^ x = 0xAB`. **Congrats, you've recovered one byte from your lost key.** Repeat another 255 times.

If somehow you compute a byte wrong, don't worry; once you have the entire key, errors in the decoded text will be obvious and you'll be able to go back and fix the corresponding key byte.